# Read data with php

Tags: php, text

Any one know how to read this data with php ?

```
a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:25:"1 whole fish, skin intact";s:4:"note";s:0:"";}i:1;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:22:"4 1/2 cups kosher salt";s:4:"note";s:0:"";}i:2;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:14:"3-4 egg whites";s:4:"note";s:0:"";}i:3;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:13:"1/4 cup water";s:4:"note";s:0:"";}i:4;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:105:"aromatics of your choice (garlic cloves, lemon wedges, bay leaves, shallots, sprigs of thyme and parsely)";s:4:"note";s:0:"";}}
```

Comment: That's a serialized php array. `$hello = unserialize('the string in your question'); var_dump($hello);`

Comment: In my opinion, we should chill a bit with the down voting on this question. Sure, it doesn't contain any attempts, but if you have no idea what that string is, how would you even start searching for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.unserialize.php) to convert this serialized array back into an array.

Example:

```
$serialized = 'a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:25:"1 whole fish, skin intact";s:4:"note";s:0:"";}i:1;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:22:"4 1/2 cups kosher salt";s:4:"note";s:0:"";}i:2;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:14:"3-4 egg whites";s:4:"note";s:0:"";}i:3;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:13:"1/4 cup water";s:4:"note";s:0:"";}i:4;a:2:{s:4:"name";s:105:"aromatics of your choice (garlic cloves, lemon wedges, bay leaves, shallots, sprigs of thyme and parsely)";s:4:"note";s:0:"";}}';

var_dump(unserialize($serialized)); // array
```

Comment: That solved my problem. Thanks for your help I appreciate it :D.